# web service in a protected folder by forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, web-services, forms-authentication

if I place my web service [ that is going to be used by a specific role ] in a folder that access is limited to that role by forms authentication , would be any more action needed to prevent unauthorized users from accessing the web service ?

Answer (score 1):

Webservices are not designed to be accessed via a browser. Forms authentication is designed for authentication via a web site browser. So forms authentication would not work so well unless the client accessing the web service is able to authenticate via a form submission,  receive, store and transmit the resultant session information while accessing the web service.

It would be better to use a different authentication provider, such as ActiveDirectory or oAuth

There are plenty of options:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication/simple-web-service-authentication

Comment: thank you sir , but this web service is not going to be used by external clients . it's used by one of my protected aspx pages to do some AJAX jobs using jquery . the user who's using this aspx page must be already logged in through login page .